# redirect and fake the referer at the sametime

Tags: php, redirect, http-referer

Is there a way to redirect the user to another site and fake the referrer at the same time.?
Tried this with my code, i know its wrong but thats only how far i can get.

```
<?php
    $page1 = "http://google.com"; $page2 = "http://yahoo.com/";
    $mypages = array($page1,$page2); 
    $myrandompage = $mypages[mt_rand(0, count($mypages) -1)];
    $sites = array_map("trim", file("links.txt"));
    $referer = $sites[array_rand($sites)];

function fake_it($url, $ref, $agent) 
{ 
  $curl = curl_init(); 
  $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
  $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank. 

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5000); 

  $html = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  // returns the content provided by the site
  return $html;
}

//Below would send a request to the url, with the second parameter as the referrer
echo fake_it($myrandompage, $referer,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

?>
```

what i want is to go from refer.php -> google.com(referer = some other url)..

Comment: That's no redirect. But apart from that it looks OK at first sight. What is going wrong, and how can you tell?

Comment: i know its not redirect thats why i said its wrong. i know its wrong because in the address bar its says `http://localhost/redirect/refer.php` instead of yahoo.com

Comment: Well, I think that's not possible. You can't tell your browser you're actually Yahoo, while you aren't. You can redirect to Yahoo using `header('Location: http://www.yahoo.com');`, but that is just a plain redirect without you being able to influence the referer. The world would be an awkward place to live in if what you want would be so easily possible. :)

Comment: If you want to see yahoo.com and it is just your local pc, you can put yahoo.com in your hosts file and point it to 127.0.0.1. That way you can go to yahoo.com, although you will probably have troubles getting actual content from the real yahoo.com. :)

Comment: The user's browser would have to make the request to the site (not cURL) and the browser would have to have a plugin or something that allows the referrer to be spoofed.  You can't control that from your website.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to redirect a user to a https site, like [damianb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783103/damianb) described ***+*** do a meta refresh on your redirect.php script:

**redirect.php:** (e.g https://www.myurl.com/redirect.php?url=http://www.someotherurl.com)

```
<?php $destination = $_GET['url']; ?>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $destination; ?>/"></head><body></body></html>
```

Now you fight with 2 weapons (https, and for browsers that still send the referer: a refresh tag).

In RFC 2616 it says:

*1. "If a website is accessed from a HTTP Secure (HTTPS) connection and a link points to anywhere except another secure location, then the referer field is not send"*

But since this is not fully true.. unfortunately, you can consider this too:

*2. "Most web browsers do not send the referer field when they are instructed to redirect using the "Refresh" field. This does not include some versions of Opera and many mobile web browsers. However, this method of redirection is discouraged by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C).[7]"*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer#Referer_hiding

Tested with Chrome and Firefox. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change referrers at all.

The only way I know of to *trash* referrers is to either proxy the page loads with something like cURL (which is bad idea, bad bad), or I believe you can go from an HTTPS page outbound.

I am not absolutely sure, but I seem to recall that browsers don't send referrers when they're coming from an HTTPS site for security reasons.

Lemme double-check.

EDIT: According to RFC 2616, browsers should not send referrers when coming from an HTTPS secured site.

reference: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-15.1.3

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure)
> HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure
> protocol.