# Headers are not setting using Referrer-Policy

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers, referrer-policy

I have a domain lets say `www.example.com` which I am redirecting to `www.whatismyreferer.com` to check referer. When I redirect the page using PHP headers it shows No referer / hidden in result. I want to set referer as `www.example.com` on `whatismyrefer.com`.

### Here is my code on the `index.php` file of `www.example.com`:

```
<?php

header("Referrer-Policy: origin");
header("Location: https://www.whatismyreferer.com",true, 302);
?>
```

I have also tried `referrer-policy: unsafe-url` but it still gets no referer

### But if I use:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;https://www.whatismyreferer.com">
```

then it shows the referrer. I don't want to do it with meta tags, I want to do it with header `location`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is probably how you are testing it. The 3xx redirect preserves the original `Referer` - the browser won't set a *new* `Referer` on the redirect itself. So, if you are directly requesting `index.php` on your site (no referer) then there will also be no referer on the redirected request.

The meta refresh is not a 3xx HTTP redirect and behaves like you are following a regular anchor/link, so the browser generates a `Referer`.

Instead, you would need to test with a secondary file (eg. `test-referer.html`) that links to `index.php` in order to generate a `Referer` before testing your redirect/`Referrer-Policy` header.

```
<!-- test-referer.html -->
<a href="/index.php">index.php</a>
```

**UPDATE:**

The `Referrer-Policy` header works correctly for me when tested in this way.

> I want to set referer as [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) on whatismyrefer.com

In that case, you can't simply use 3xx HTTP redirects (without an initial referrer) because 3xx redirects don't themselves generate a referrer (as mentioned above). If 3xx redirects generated a `Referer` then sites would have problems with lost referrers all the time due to canonical redirects etc.

You will need to use a meta refresh (as you suggested) or perhaps a JavaScript "redirect" (untested). Or you could perhaps use CURL if the intention is to simply "fake" the `Referer` - although this won't directly result in a redirect.

Comment: basically what i want to do is this FIRST DOMAIN-->(Redirect to 2nd Domain)-->Redirect to final domain which should show 2nd domain as referer)

Comment: Ok, but you can't simply use 3xx HTTP redirects for that (without an initial referrer) -  because that's not how 3xx redirects work. The `Referrer-Policy` header is otherwise working as intended. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This [other question has code that uses CURL to fake the `Referer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234291/redirect-and-fake-the-referer-at-the-sametime) - but note that this is not a _redirect_, hence why the answers suggest other methods, such as the meta refresh, as mentioned here.